# Yii CGridView custom footer

Tags: yii

I am using CGridView to show data in grid format, but i am not able to create a custom footer, 
the code that i am using,

```
<?php
      $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',
           array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
           'columns' => array(
               array(
                   'name' => 'created_date',
                   'header' => 'Created',
               ),
               array(
                   'name' => 'access_date',
                   'header' => 'Accessed',
               ),
               array(
                   'name' => 'referenceCode',
                   'header' => 'Ref Code',
               ),
               array(
                   'name' => 'designation',
                   'header' => 'Designation',
               ),                  
               array(
                   'name' => 'company',
                   'header' => 'Company',
               ),
               array(
                        'name' => 'recommended_actions',
                        'header' => 'Recommended Action',
                        'type' => 'html',
                        'value' => function($jobBoard) {
                            return CHtml::link($recAction[0]['display_text'], Yii::app()->createUrl($actionUrl, $params));
                        }
                    ),
               array(
                   'class' => 'CDataColumn',
                   'header' => 'List of Actions',
                   'type' => 'html',
                   'value' => function($jobBoard){
                        echo '<div class="action-joborder">
                                <ul class="moveto-joborder">
                                    <li>Action <img height="6" width="7" alt="" src="images/bg_action.gif">
                                    <ul>';
                                      echo '<li>'.CHtml::link($actionArray['display_text'], Yii::app()->createUrl($actionUrl, $params)).'</li>';                
                              echo '</ul>
                                </li>
                                </ul>
                               </div>';                        
                   },
                   'name' => 'actions',                    
               ),
    )));         
?>
```

the above code gives me footer with pagination only, i want to place a some Button element to give the grid some control.
the grid should look like,
[image]

is there any way i can make custom element at the footer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php and use it in your code. extend the following method to change footer

```
public function renderTableFooter()
{
  $hasFilter=$this->filter!==null && $this->filterPosition===self::FILTER_POS_FOOTER;
  $hasFooter=$this->getHasFooter();
  if($hasFilter || $hasFooter)
  {
    echo "<tfoot>\n";
    if($hasFooter)
    {
      echo "<tr>\n";
      foreach($this->columns as $column)
              $column->renderFooterCell();
      echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    if($hasFilter)
      $this->renderFilter();
    echo "</tfoot>\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

protected/components/GridView.php

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');


class GridView extends CGridView
{

/**
 * Renders the table footer.
 */
public function renderTableFooter()
{
    $hasFilter=$this->filter!==null && $this->filterPosition===self::FILTER_POS_FOOTER;
    $hasFooter=$this->getHasFooter();
    if($hasFilter || $hasFooter)
    {
        echo "<tfoot>\n";
        if($hasFooter)
        {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            foreach($this->columns as $column){
                if($column->footer!='')
                    $column->footer=eval("return " . $column->footer.";");

                $column->renderFooterCell();
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        if($hasFilter)
            $this->renderFilter();
        echo "</tfoot>\n";
    }
}

public function sumTotal($attribute){
    $data=$this->dataProvider->getData();

    $sum=0;
    foreach($data as $index => $value ){

        if(isset($data[$index]->{$attribute}))
            $sum+=$data[$index]->{$attribute};
    }

    return $sum;
}

}
```

views/{controllers}/{action}.php

```
  $this->widget('GridView',
       array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'columns' => array(
           array(
               'name' => 'created_date',
               'header' => 'Created',
           ),
           array(
               'name' => 'access_date',
               'header' => 'Accessed',
           ),
           array(
               'name' => 'referenceCode',
               'header' => 'Ref Code',
           ),
           array(
               'name' => 'designation',
               'header' => 'Designation',
           ),                  
           array(
               'name' => 'company',
               'header' => 'Company',
           ),
           array(
                    'name' => 'recommended_actions',
                    'header' => 'Recommended Action',
                    'type' => 'html',
                    'value' => function($jobBoard) {
                        return CHtml::link($recAction[0]['display_text'], Yii::app()->createUrl($actionUrl, $params));
                    }
                    'footer'=> 'number_format($this->sumTotal("recommended_actions"))',

           ),
           array(
               'class' => 'CDataColumn',
               'header' => 'List of Actions',
               'type' => 'html',
               'value' => function($jobBoard){
                    echo '<div class="action-joborder">
                            <ul class="moveto-joborder">
                                <li>Action <img height="6" width="7" alt="" src="images/bg_action.gif">
                                <ul>';
                                  echo '<li>'.CHtml::link($actionArray['display_text'], Yii::app()->createUrl($actionUrl, $params)).'</li>';                
                          echo '</ul>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                           </div>';                        
               },
               'name' => 'actions',                    
           ),
)));
```